# VSCode: React (or globally) disable auto imports

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, auto-import

I'm using the Javascript code snippets extenstion in VSCode, which is very useful.
Typing 'clo' and pressing tab is a default shortcut for creating a console log of an object.

The problem I'm having is that when I accidentally write 'cli' and press tab, the following is imported at the top of thejsx file. It does not happen in .js files:

```
import cli from "eslint/lib/cli";
```

This is extremely annoying. What I've tried to fix it:

- Turning off Suggest > Auto Imports for both Javascript and Typescript
- Adding an auto import exclude pattern for eslint
- Creating a User Snippet to override it
- Digging in the eslint extension files to find something relevant